# How to set the YouTube app to play 360p instead of 240p video?

Tags: youtube

In the YouTube app there are only options to play 144p or 240p. Is there any way to make it play 360p?

When I access YouTube from Chrome it plays 360p videos; the quality of the same video was way better when played from the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling the YouTube app, option for playing 360p is back.

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube quality settings are determined by each video (although if you select a higher quality, it will default to that for the next time).  Hit the three-dot menu button:

[image]

Then the Quality cog button:

[image]

Then you can select the quality setting.

[image]

Other videos might have more options for the quality setting:

[image]

This completely depends on external factors like, for example, the size of the source video that was uploaded to YouTube.

You can also (from the 3-dot menu on the app Home) go to Settings → General to turn off the "Limit mobile data usage" option, which will allow videos to default to higher quality when you are not on Wi-Fi.